# How to Format Description when writing Help for Python script tool?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, arcgis-9.3

I try to format the description in script tool but I don't know how it works so i don't manage to add a line break for example.

Does it works with HTML tags ?

When editing my script the description is :

ACTIONS : Pour toutes les images tif dans un dossier

- Converti les image .tif en Polygon et les enregistre dans un autre dossier

  LES INPUTS :
- Le Dossier ...

But when opening the script window to execute, the description is as on the picture :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/PZ8eHcy.png]

(without break lines)

Thanks

To Edit my script i use this :

[image]

Comment: Are you using the page editor? You should be able to add break points and other formatting, check http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Using_the_page_editor

Comment: I don't know what you call the page editor. I am beginner with arcGis and Python. I add a picture in my post to show what i use to edit and run my script. Is that the page editor ?

Comment: You're not using the page editor. With version 9.3 the simplest way to add more than just plain text to your tool description (or add a description for parameters, etc), is to use the page and documentation editors... Have you checked the link above? Check this one also to get started: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_the_Documentation_Editor

Comment: @GISGe I think you should propose an Answer based on your Comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, actually with 9.3 you can't edit the tool's abstract in the tool side panel with the page editor, so you can only use plain text. You can use the page editor for most items of the tool's help page, see [Entering topics in the Documentation Editor](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Entering_topics_in_the_Documentation_Editor). 
Apologies for the confusion, I haven't used 9.3 for years, by the way it's not supported anymore.
Since 10.0 there is a nicer editing interface with different formatting options like bullet points, indentation and hyperlinks, see picture below.

[image]